# How to display a type blob image to ejs web page?

Tags: mysql, node.js, blob, ejs

I created a database using long blob and stored my images in it. Then I wanted to display the images to one of my ejs web pages. However, it shows up as weird lettering. I know that I am supposed to convert it so that it works I just don't know how to do it.

This is what shows up when I run my node-js server: 
[image]

This is the code that I am using in ejs:

```
               <% for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) { console.log(products[i]); %>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell" data-title="Brand">
                    <td><%= products[i].brand %></td>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell" data-title="Model">
                    <td><%= products[i].model %></td>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell" data-title="Series">
                    <td><%= products[i].series %></td>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell" data-title="Preview">
                    <td><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<%- products[i].image01 %>" /></td>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <% } %>
```

There are many posts that show how to do it in javascript, but is there a way to do it in ejs? Also, most of the ways that I found look really long, so I am trying to be as efficient as possible. Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you need to convert your binary data to base64 format & then pass it to ejs. You can do this in NodeJS using `Buffer`.

Try this:

`products[i] = new Buffer(products[i]).toString('base64');`

Hope this helps!